# Using limit parameter in paginate function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-pagination

Is it possible to use 'limit' parameter in paginate() function?

I'm trying this:

```
$users->where(...)->limit(50)->paginate($page)
```

...and now, if I have 100 users in the database then the response from paginate function will be all 100 users instead of 50 (or number of users defined with limit parameter).

So, my question is: is it possible to implement limit parameter when I use paginate function?

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not possible to limit the query when using pagination.

Query pagination uses `skip()` and `limit()` internally to select the proper records. Any `limit()` applied to the query will be overwritten by the pagination requirements.

If you'd like to paginate a subset of results, you will need to get the results first, and then manually create a paginator for those results.

Answer (score 0):

Use LengthAwarePaginator.

Example:

```
$total = 50;
$perPage = 10;
$users = $users->where(...)->paginate($page);

$users = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $users->toArray()['data'], 
    $users->total() < $total ? $users->total() : $total, 
    $perPage, 
    $page
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use limit in Laravel query then will we use offset for pagination.

First time

> $users->where(...)->limit(10)->offset(0);

On next click

> $users->where(...)->limit(10)->offset(10);

More next click

> $users->where(...)->limit(10)->offset(20);

Answer (score 0):

as @patricus said it's not possible, but you can take a walk around to get what you want, it will be something like:

```
$users=User::where(...)->limit(50);
$users=$user->paginate(10);
```

this trick works for me, but after some thinking, I realized I'm really didn't need to apply this solution as pagination already limit the query. All what you need is the right query for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

> By default, the current page is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request. Of course, this value is automatically detected by Laravel, and is also automatically inserted into links generated by the paginator.

So, inform page and pagination and all should be fine.