# laravel paginate 1000 last Record with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

How can I get and paginate the last 1000 records with relationship?

i try this but this return all data

```
$logbooks = $this->log_book->orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(10000)->take(1000)->paginate(100);
```

Comment: remove `->skip(10000)` and try

Comment: You probably also want to use limit(1000), instead of take().

Comment: `take()` is just an alias for `limit()`

Comment: No, it's not possible to limit the query when using pagination.

Query pagination uses skip() and limit() internally to select the proper records. Any limit() applied to the query will be overwritten by the pagination requirements

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473707/using-limit-parameter-in-paginate-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using limit parameter in paginate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473707/using-limit-parameter-in-paginate-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only what can i do is use this macro for pagination on collection, so add this code to my AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
    $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($this->forPage($page, $perPage), $total ?: $this->count(), $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => $pageName,
    ]);
});
```

Then i will paginate on the collection

```
$logbooks = $this->log_book->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(1000)->get();
$logbooks->paginate(100);
```