# Pagination pages problem collection / array

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-9, paginator

I've used the query builder instead of the normal select(I had to, I have added pagination).
query builder example :

```
$dataGlobal = DB::table('articles')
->orderBy('articleDate', 'desc')
->orderBy('articleHour', 'desc')
->orderBy('articleMinute', 'asc')
->orderBy('articleSeconde', 'asc')
->limit(150)
->paginate(15);
```

With this code, normally I shoud have 10 pages no more, but instead of the 10 pages I have 23. Counting from page 5 to 23, all of these pages aren't working with this error code; **Undefined array key 0**

For the pagination I'm using the bootstrap 5 blade pagination (vendor folder)

My question is why am I having all of theese pages ? The weird thing is I have this problem in one page only which is my home page, but in the other ones I don't have this problem at all everything is good

Maybe I didn't give enought details let me know if you guys need me to add something.

Comment: ->paginate(15) means 15 items per page, not 15 pages

Comment: @SCHYNSAnthony yes my bad I wanted to say 10 pages*

Comment: What happens if you do `php artisan optimize:clear`? Does that fixes it?

Comment: @DanielL same problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't do anything else with $dataGlobal , maybe post the rest of the code

Comment: @MatthewPage you are right ! I've forgot a treatment where I use $dataGlobal... all good now

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't use limit with pagination.

see this answer: [Using limit parameter in paginate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473707/using-limit-parameter-in-paginate-function)

Comment: At the beginning I wasn’t using limit. I have added it just to test that’s all. But I’ve the same problem without using limit